# Add prefix and remove space for 'option' in 'optgroup'

Tags: css, html-select

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This returns:

```
Swedish Cars
  Volvo
  Saab
German Cars
  Mercedes
  Audi
```

This is ok, but I would like to add before Volvo, Saab, Mercedes and Audi own prefix, for example ">" and remove empty space like this:

```
 Swedish Cars
 >Volvo
 >Saab 
 German Cars
 >Mercedes
 >Audi
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Css styling does not work on them and there is not option that does this.

What you can do is:

- use just the `option` tag and add the `>` manually or with javascript.
- make a custom drop-down menu like [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/how-to-create-custom-select-menus-with-css.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible in javascript.

Do this:

```
var myArr = document.querySelectorAll('optgroup > option');
for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
  myArr[i].textContent = ">"+ myArr[i].textContent;
}
```

Comment: This does not remove the space as he requested.